# Why is SQL Server Linked Server Oracle not (always) passing where-clause to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, performance, oledbconnection

I am searching for possibility to make a (newly created) linked server (to oracle)  as fast as the one which already is very fast.

**Following situation on a windows Server with SQL Server installed**

- Linked_Server_1 to Oracle Server A  (11.2.0.4)
- Linked_Server_2 to Oracle Server B  (19.3.0.0)
- Oracle Client Version on Server with SQL Server Database: 19.3.0.0  (Oracle Provider for OLE Db)

**Queries sent to Linked_Server_1 perform very well:**

```
SELECT vpnrlfd 
FROM oracle11204..SYSADM.LPOS_VIEW 
WHERE VPNRLFD=1235;
```

> result is 1 row in <1s; 1 of 100 mio rows

th Oracle Session Trace looks like this:

```
SELECT "Tbl1002"."VPNRLFD" "Col1004"
FROM "SYSADM"."LPOS_VIEW" "Tbl1002"
**WHERE** "Tbl1002"."VPNRLFD" = (1235.)
```

> 1 of 1 mio rows

**Same query from Linked_Server_2 performs extremly slow:**

```
SELECT vpnrlfd 
FROM oracle19300..SYSADM.LPOS_VIEW
WHERE VPNRLFD=1235;
```

Oracle Session Trace:

```
SELECT *
FROM "SYSADM"."LPOS_VIEW"
```

> needs hours (all of 100 mio rows)

What could be the reason, why the where-clause  is not passed trough to the oracle on Linked_Server_2 whereas with Linked_Server_1 this is the case.

The linked server properties are identical, except those for the oracle server name an login

I have reduced the involved data type to numeric to avoid Character coding issues.
i have tried with different versions of Oracle Client installed on the Server containing the SQL Server with linked server.
i have tried on another SQL Server machine with exactly same results (one is fast, the other slow)

There is a different behaviour depending on to which oracle database server the query is forwarded. Unfortunately I have no more ideas where to look further.

I suppose, the reason and hopefully the solution lies on the side of the oracle Database server., (??)

Thanks in advance you for any inputs

edit dec.12 2021:
linked Server does pass the where clause when the query target is a table at the oracle side. When the target is a view  then the where clause is not passed.  However this does work with the oracle2 11.0.4 Database

edit dec.12. 2021:
linked server passes the where clause also when the query target is a view on then oracle side. BUT when the view reaches a certain amount of total row count (select count(*) from view) linked server stops passing the where clause.

who wants to help me find out what makes this system decide whether the where clause is passed through or not passed through to the remote Database?

Comment: I don't know about Oracle, but on older versions of SQL Server there used to be an issue with not having permission to use column statistics (aka histograms) on the remote server. I would check if changing the login on your new linked server "fixes" the issue and, if it does, compare permissions between the two logins on the Oracle side.

Comment: Changed login to one with oracle dba role but did not fix the issue. Even login as oracle built in "system" user has no effect.  I found your idea realy promising, however ...